# I do not see a warning anymore when downloading a PDF file!

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Tor Browser Bundle version 3.5 for windows does not show any warning when a PDF file is about to download. Is it a feature or a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the PDF inside the web browser it is safe.

If you download it and then open it in another PDF viewer it is maybe not safe. If you believe a warning should be shown in this case, but it is not, you should report it as a bug.

https://trac.torproject.org/